# Call to a member function save() on integer

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to do a simple save but I get this error.

> Call to a member function save() on integer

Here is my code from controller:

```
foreach ($request['array'] as $key => $value) {

    if(DB::table('users')->where('id',$value)->where('auth',0)->exists() == true){
        $c = DB::table('users')->where('id', $value);
        $c->auth_teacher = '1';
        $c->update();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Made changes now I get this:

> update() must be of the type array, none given

Answer (score 0):

because you are setting $c to 1 on this line:

```
       $c = DB::table('users')->where('id', $value)->auth_teacher = 1;
```

Comment: I tried it but now i get error update() must be of the type array, none given

Comment: You have to fetch the record, which you haven't. $c now only contains the query. To actually fetch the record, do $c = DB::table('users')->where('id', $value)->first();

Comment: now i get "Call to undefined method stdClass::update()"

Comment: what does  $c = DB::table('users')->where('id', $value)->first()OrFail(); return?

Comment: "Call to undefined method stdClass::OrFail()"

Comment: oops, typo, try : $c = DB::table('users')->where('id', $value)->firstOrFail(); instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130159/discussion-between-pseudoanime-and-ounknowno).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
  foreach ($request['array'] as $key => $value) {

    if(DB::table('users')->where('id',$value)->where('auth',0)->exists() == true){
       DB::table('users')->where('id', $value)->update(['auth_teacher' => 1]);
    }

  }
```